# Django ModelForm and datetimefield : no widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I try to display a modelform containing a datetime field.

But when I try to display this field, nothing appears.

In the model form, when I print self.fields :

```
{'status': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x1340e10>, 'reserved': <django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0x1340cd0>, 'date_publication': None, 'date_creation': None}
```

Here's the model :

```
class News(MultiLangModel):
 date_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("Date"))
 date_publication = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("Publication date"))
 status        = models.CharField(max_length=10,         verbose_name=_("Status"), choices=POST_STATUS_CHOICES)
 reserved   = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_(u"News reserved to supporters"))
```

What can be the reason of this bug ?

Answer (score 3):

You have set the `auto_now_add` attribute to `True` for `date_publication`. This implies that the value of this field will be set *automatically* and not from user input. To verify this remove the `auto_now_add` attribute and try again.

From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for `auto_now_add`:

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is *always* used; it's not just a default value that you can override.